# Angular 6x CLI: How to suppress SCSS compilation warnings in dev console

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

When I compile my Angular project I'm getting warnings for autoprefixer:

```
[WDS] Warnings while compiling.

./src/app/administration/user/user.component.scss
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) autoprefixer:
auto-rows is not supported by IE
```

There are several issues on Angular's Github but they relate to other package warnings such as Bazel. Can I suppress specific or all warnings permanently?

Answer (score 1):

Update `browserslist` file in `src` folder to this value

```
last 1 version
> 5%
not dead
not ie > 1
not ie_mob > 1
```

`last 1 version` : just the latest version for each browser.

`>5%` : browsers versions selected by global usage statistics.

`not ie , not ie_mob > 1` : exclude all IE and IE Mobile from target browsers.

[browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist)

Comment: Awesome! I looked through the git you linked to but are there explanations for what those commands mean?

Comment: I have add explanations about browserslist queries @BenRacicot